# I can't access my admin page after changing main url

Tags: wp-admin

I have change the main URL of my wordpress theme.
I accessed `Admin area => Settings => and change my URL from : 
www.sampleURL.com to www.sampleURL.com/?page_id=2`

and now every time I enter `www.sampleURL.com/wp-admin` i get directed to `www.sampleURL.com/?page_id=2`

Please help!

Comment: Can you get to the following URL? `www.sampleURL.com/wordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php` If so, change the setting back from the admin panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to make that change, but if worst comes to worst, you can change it back via the database. Assuming you can access your MySQL database directly, simple navigate to the wp_options table and change the value of `siteurl` and/or `home` to your desired values.

EDIT: Alternatively, if you can access your code, in the theme's functions.php file, add the following code.

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://sampleURL.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://sampleURL.com' );
```

Obviously, swap http://sampleURL.com with your URL. Then refresh the home page of your site a couple times. Once everything is back to normal, remove this code.

Comment: I can't access my mysql directly. :( I only got ftp connection, where would I go it I want to access my mysql?

Comment: Well that depends on your host. I assume this is a self-hosted blog?

Comment: Do you have access to the theme files via FTP? i.e. can you modify the code?

Comment: yes I can access and modify it.

Comment: I have edited my answer with another solution which should be easier for you.

Comment: Oh my! It works! Thank you so much for help Chris! thanks a lot..

Comment: Glad I could help.