# Unable to get to the admin panel

Tags: admin, login

I am using WordPress on one of the sites. I admit that I have been blitheringly idiotic not testing on a dev server, but I updated all the plugins today. They were akismet, custom login and wp security.

Now the problem is that I am unable to get to the wordpress login panel. I had changed the login url using one of the plugins custom login or wp security or both, I am sure I don't remember. The login page url sends me to the not found page.

I have already tried disabling all the plugins from the database by applying `a:0:{}` in active_plugins in the options table on the wordpress database.

Comment: Just delete the plugins directly using ftp. Wordpress will then deactivate them as they are no longer there

Comment: @PieterGoosen, I think deactivating the plugins from the db should work well enough. Anyway, I did try moving out the plugins. Didn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution.

After searching the whole of the WordPress database, I got the "divine" inspiration to check out the .htaccess file. The custom-login script had modified the file. I just removed the line `RewriteRule ^.*wp-admin/?|^.*wp-login\.php /not_found [R,L]` and everything started working again.

Comment: Great that you found a solution, and thanks for taking the time posting it. +1

Comment: @PieterGoosen and others thanks for your helpful attitude

Answer (score 1):

Rather than delete, rename all the updateded directories (e.g. akismet-off) via ftp and then try logging in again.

Answer (score 0):

If Pieter's comment doesn't work (and it's a good suggestion) then you need to go into MySQL using PhpMyAdmin or similar and change the URL.
The following post should help guide you through in greater detail:
http://wordpress.shadowlantern.com/how-change-wordpress-url-phpmyadmin/

Comment: sorry @TomC that won't work in my case as the site is working OK, I am only not able to get access to the panel.

Comment: There are two options for Wordpress URL and Admin URL. This link may be better: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25271/i-cant-access-my-admin-page-after-changing-main-url

Comment: Thanks for you looking it up, but the answer is a bit off from what I was seeking.